# python regex forcing new line

Tags: python, regex

Why is my regular expression adding am line break before the closing tag?

```
string = '\s ప్రపంచ ప్రారంభం'
re.sub(r'\\s (.*)', r'<h3>\1</h3>', string)
```

what I get

```
<h3>ప్రపంచ ప్రారంభం
</h3>
```

what I want

```
<h3>ప్రపంచ ప్రారంభం</h3>
```

Comment: Interesting. I don't get that. I get what you want.

Comment: I changed my OP. Maybe it has something to do with the fact the language is rtl?

Comment: It works just fine for me ... but do you really need `regex` for this?  `string = '<h3>%s</h3>'%string[3:] if string.startswith(r'\s ') else '<h3>%s</h3>'%string` seems like it would work ...

Comment: Just as an added point it's not a good idea to overwrite inbuilt classes... avoid using `string` if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the text part of your string, make sure there's nothing there creating a line break.  When I tried:

```
s = '\s hi world'
re.sub(r'\\s (.*)', r'<h3>\1</h3>', s)
```

I got:

```
'<h3>hi world</h3>'
```

I was using Python 2.7.3.